# MySQL: Update using a join takes a really long time

Tags: mysql, join

I've got an update statement that uses a join that is taking a really long time.  I'll provide more detail below but here is the query:

```
update quote_line
left join quote q on (q.id = quote_id and q.version = version )
set quote_serial_id = q.serial_id
```

Backstory: I'm trying to clean up a DB that I've inherited.  I have two tables with the following schema (only important columns shown):

quote:

```
serial_id  bigint(20)  -- Unique key defined with 'serial'
id         bigint(20)  -- Id of quote.
version    smallint(6) -- Version of quote.
```

quote_line:

```
id         bigint(20)  -- Unique key defined with 'serial'
quote_id   bigint(20)  -- Foreign key to quote.
version    smallint(6) -- Foreign key to quote.
```

Note that quote.id is *not* a key, however quote.id+quote.version is.  For whatever reason the designer decided to use id+version as the foreign key in quote_line instead of serial_id.  To make this concrete here is how a join *must* be done:

```
select q.id, q.version, q.serial_id
from quote q join quote_line l on q.id = l.quote_id and l.version = q.version
```

I want to change the FK in quote_line to use quote.serial_id, which gives me this update statement:

```
update quote_line
left join quote q on (q.id = quote_id and q.version = version )
set quote_serial_id = q.serial_id
```

This statement, after hours of running, still isn't finished.  I've tried creating indexes on quote with no improvement.  I'm running MySQL 5.5.14 so I can't run explain on the update.  The two tables have this many rows:

quote: 335517
quote_line: 247992

You can see that not all quotes have quote_lines (in fact, most of them do not).  Any hints on how to make this run faster?  I eventually have to replicate this on our production servers and I can't have it taking hours.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are only interested in updating quote_lines, and not all quotes have lines, what's the purpose of the LEFT join (why not INNER)?

Comment: Wouldn't the left join set quote_serial_id to NULL when there is no quote. In other words it handles quote_lines with no associated quote, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments by Paul and sceaj I was using a LEFT join.  When I removed the 'LEFT' the query ran in a few seconds.  Thanks for the help!